# Is it possible to create an array of names of variables?

Tags: c

I have a table of variables.

```
int var1;
int var2;
int var3;
```

I would like to access values of those variables either explicitly by name, like `var1 = 3;` or as an array (in a `for` loop):

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(vars_array) / sizeof(int); i++)
{
    vars_array[i] = nnn;
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you explain the use case?

Comment: Why aree you using separate variables instead of an array in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for the replies and comments. It was a bad idea as I see it now. I'll use the array alone and create a constant definition for each array index to access in a sort of 'by name', like `vars_array[VAR1]`

Comment: This is what pointers are for.

Comment: In environments where they are available, this can be possible with `dlopen() / dlsym()`, but it's a terrible idea (other than for just funnin' around).

Comment: @AlexanderZhak [Consider using an enum for that](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/enum.html).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use:

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(vars_array); i++)
{
    vars_array[i] = nnn;
}
```

However, if you are willing to store an array of pointers, you can use:

```
int* vars_array[] = {&var1, &var2, &var3};
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(vars_array)/sizeof(vars_array[0]); i++)
{
    *vars_array[i] = nnn;
}
```

Comment: You are assuming sizeof(int) == 1. This is likely incorrect.

Comment: A better technique is to end `vars_array` with `NULL` and check `vars_array[i] != NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this.  (Note: you might be able to pull it off with some sort of horrid memory map, don't do it).  You generally want to avoid dynamically referencing variables by name *even if the language allows it*.  It makes understanding the code very difficult.  What you want instead is an array or [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) to store and retrieve data in pairs.

If the variables are simply numbered `var1`, `var2`, `var3`... then instead of using individual variables, put the values in an array.

```
int vars[] = { 23, 42, 99 };
for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
    printf("vars%d: %d\n", i, vars[i]);
}
```

If the variable names are not numbers, or the numbers are not contiguous, then the general idea is to use a hash table.  This is like an array, but instead of using numbers of the index it uses strings.  Lookup is fast, but it inherently has no order.

C doesn't have hashes built in, so you'll have to use a library like [Gnome Lib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html).

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    /* Init a hash table to take strings for keys */
    GHashTable *vars = g_hash_table_new(g_str_hash, g_str_equal);

    /* For maximum flexibility, GHashTable expects the keys and
       values to be void pointers, but you can safely store
       integers by casting them */
    g_hash_table_insert(vars, "this", (gpointer)23);
    g_hash_table_insert(vars, "that", (gpointer)42);
    g_hash_table_insert(vars, "whatever", (gpointer)99);

    /* And casting the "pointer" back to an integer */
    printf("'this' is %d\n", (int)g_hash_table_lookup(vars, "this"));

    g_hash_table_unref(vars);

    return 0;
}
```

[Here's a good tutorial on using Gnome Lib](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/tutorials/l-glib/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll take a look at the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. You would need a union:

```
union {
 struct {
  int var1, var2, var3;
 };
 int vars_array[3];
}name;
```

Although this way you should prefix your variable instances with 'name.'. You can't omit it and export the identifiers in the enclosing space (as unnamed structure and union members) for some reason.

Your code for accessing array elements (which directly map to your variables - eventually?) should look like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(name.vars_array) / sizeof(int); i++)
{
    name.vars_array[i] = nnn;
}
```

Comment: OK but I decided to try a new thing you know.